# MVC Use RenderPartial to access class List

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to access a class's properties that are within the main class (model).

Attempting this through @Html.RenderPartial but cannot seem to access the class within the class in the partial view - where am I going wrong in how to access the class lists properties?

**main cshtml**

```
@model Project.Models.BaseClass

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="ui-block-a">
                        <p>Heading</p>
                        <span>@{Html.RenderPartial("~/View/Path", Model);}</span>
                    </div>
</body
</html>
```

**partial view** - doesn't work

```
@model Project.Models.BaseClass.ChildClass
```

**model**

```
public class BaseClass
{
public List<ChildClass> childclasslist {get;set;}
}
public class ChildClass
{
public string name {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your main view you have the model from type `BaseClass`. So with the statement

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("~/View/Path", Model);}
```

you are giving the partial view the model `BaseClass`.

But your partial view expects a model from type

```
Project.Models.BaseClass.ChildClass
```

(which doesn't even exist, it would be `Project.Models.ChildClass`).

---

### There are two options:

Change your partial view:

```
@model Project.Models.BaseClass
```

and access your list like

```
Model.childclasslist
```

**or**

Change your call to render the partial view:

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("~/View/Path", Model.childclasslist);}
```

and your partial view:

```
@model List<Project.Models.ChildClass>
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks for that, especially the explanation, will accept when it allows.

Answer (score 1):

How i can see, your ChildClass has similar namespace with BaseClass.
Try using correct namespace

```
@model Project.Models.ChildClass
```